# Determinant of a matrix where every row other than first is a cyclic shift of the first row

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, hankel-matrices

How do you find the determinant of the following matrix?
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&\cdots&n\\2&3&\cdots&n&1\\3&\cdots&n&1&2\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\n&1&\cdots&(n-2)&(n-1)
\end{pmatrix}

(i.e. we have the first row and all the other rows are cyclic shifts of the first one)

I've tried subtracting columns from one another to get a nice triangle matrix, but after some time that seemed futile for me. What I've noticed is that whichever anti-diagonal from right to left you choose, e.g., a diagonal

\begin{pmatrix}
\require{cancel}
\cdots&\cdots&\cancel{3}&\cdots\\\cdots&\cancel{3}&\dots&\dots\\\cancel{3}&\dots&\dots&\dots
\end{pmatrix}

all of the numbers on this diagonal are similar (e.g., $(2,2), (3,3,3), (n, \dots, n)$ and so on), so maybe one can get a recurrence relation.

Comment: [Special case of Theorem 17 on page 23](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9902004).

Comment: The matrix you are looking at is an example of a [Hankel matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix)

Comment: Also, reversing the order of the rows multiplies the determinant by $(-1)^n$ and leaves you with a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).  Note that there is a formula given on the linked page for the determinant of a circulant matrix.

Comment: Thank you for you help!